# How do I download an embedded video from a website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, video-capture

I am trying to download a video from a website automatically with javascript.

Google chrome allows me to right click and "save as" a video but i have to manually click to save the video.

From what I know, the website gets the video and turns it into a blob also if you inspect(ctrl + i) the video you can get the video link.

This is one of the links I am trying to download from: https://www.wcoanimesub.tv/jojo-no-kimyou-na-bouken-tv-episode-17-english-subbed

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how I would download the embedded video?

Edit:

I would prefer not to use chrome extentions.

p.s. I don't know where to go to ask this question, so I put it here.

Comment: @Tân . No. i have tried this and it doesn't work ,also i would like to automate the download process.

Answer (score 7):

Visit the page in chrome and open ‘Developer Tool’ by press F12 or right click -> inspect element
Go to -> Networks Tab and click ‘Media’ tag in filter row
Click ‘Play’ button on the player. you will see a link in the networks tag
Just open that link in New tab. video will open in normal browser’s player.
Now right click the on the video and ‘Save’ to your local machine. 
If it is preceded by an ad make sure you have an adblocker. 
Prove it works here is 1st video on your linked page: https://disk5.cizgifilmlerizle.com/getvid?evid=wXxbWGkc-3ZZCUx6abGKPTcpL6i8XBzhDB8XKviBEOHN0gzJ1I-2z4GvZkwOH2Vl1bNzGTCv7odEnDE4TqxnlxQLG1MptkGgGR8Inf39W-Pvr-j6t_cQYYtavMV5FXxfrQmObKWMniKVA14I0Z8cpq9-DAtxeq8yGGVUOpKh74OdwA5ceKOPH_EultcyI3GPijjPxqhALm-TcinRBn8qmwsBjW_no-ciuNcw5OhehsdTsYDy_imDmFfQpg4oL_nt-EviZtCUZBdYflZa2Fjhu33UidDn6io8RDxfLMY7TyPrzgCLv6n2mNuUVfwDwPZtqKwtSVKJX-l-_SAmz5qk7kQc6AFnwaw7pKJrpV5Tr5D7k4c-O5IEZ_yoOLqQl79wna0iM7m9dv7GLRp26EhWqQ

Comment: is there a way to save the video without having to click on to the video

Comment: I have followed the same but getting this.

<Error>
<Code>InvalidKey</Code>
<Message>Unknown Key</Message>
</Error>